# Trouble connecting to some HTTPS urls

Tags: linux, ssl

I am having trouble connecting to some websites using https. wget and curl complain about not being able to verify the certificate. I presume this is to missing root certificates on my NAS. For example:

```
ReadyNAS:~# wget https://pypi.python.org/
--2016-04-12 20:08:51--  https://pypi.python.org/
Resolving pypi.python.org... 23.235.43.223
Connecting to pypi.python.org|23.235.43.223|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify pypi.python.org's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
ERROR: certificate common name `www.python.org' doesn't match requested host name `pypi.python.org'.
To connect to pypi.python.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I have manually compiled and updated both curl and wget to fairly recent versions (GNU Wget 1.11.4; libcurl/7.45.0 GnuTLS/3.3.18 zlib/1.2.3.3) but to no avail.

**Backstory:** The linux distribution on my NAS is fairly old (Debian Sid, Linux 2.6.37.6). The regular commands for updating the SSL store don't seem to have effect.

How would I find the cause of these connection issues and resolve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors:

```
ERROR: cannot verify pypi.python.org's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA': Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
```

That mean the DigiCert CA is not in the OS trust store.
You should be able to add it downloading the CA crt (i.e. from Firefox) then adding it:

`cp digicert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/digicert.crt`

`update-ca-certificates`

(I'm not really sure about these command but should work on old Debian too...)

```
ERROR: certificate common name `www.python.org' doesn't match requested host name `pypi.python.org'.
```

This mean that the cert was not issue for domain pypi.python.org, but, checking the cert with firefox i can see that pypi.python.org is listed into the certificate.
Maybe this is a false alarm caused by missing CA, try to fix it before.

[nostalgic]Awww, a good old 2.6 kernel  :D[/nostalgic]